# WGS72 to NAD83- how to find correct transformation

Tags: coordinate-system, datum

I am trying to get this raster file to convert from WGS72 to NAD83, but ArcMap10 doesn't appear to have the correct transformation listed.  Where can I find this transformation, and/or how do I import ones that are not already listed as available?

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS doesn't have any direct transformations for WGS72 to NAD83, so you would have to use two transformations. For WGS72 to WGS84, try WGS_1972_To_WGS_1984_2. For WGS84 to NAD83, try NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_5 if the data in the US.

Comment: Fantastic.  This worked great!